# Button action not called in UIviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIView Class in which I have created a button action which animate my cards swiped now in my own View controller I have created a PopUpView .PopUp having Yes and No Button i want to call those right or left action On this popUpView buttons.

```
-(void)rightClickAction{

     CGPoint finishPoint = CGPointMake(600, self.center.y);
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.center = finishPoint;
   self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1); 
                     }completion:^(BOOL complete){
                         [self removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
    [delegate cardSwipedRight:self];

    NSLog(@"YES");

 }

 -(void)leftClickAction{
      CGPoint finishPoint = CGPointMake(-600, self.center.y);
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.center = finishPoint;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1);
                     }completion:^(BOOL complete){
                         [self removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    [delegate cardSwipedLeft:self];
    NSLog(@"NO");
 }
```

what will i have to do to call it my ViewController in

```
 -(IbAction)actionYes{
        [draggableView rightClickAction];
    }

-(IBAction)actionNo{

     }
```

it is not working.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: have you set connection of popUpView button and Action?

Comment: Debug. set breakpoint you will get idea

Comment: i have done it not working..

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: No buddy not yet working on it

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a case of uicontrol sub-class events are not called too.

The following things may help you.

1.Check connection of view and ibaction in xib or storyboard.

2.Check the userinteraction property of the button's subviews.

3.Check is there has any gesture made on the button.

4.Check if the viewcontroller was dealloced.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DraggableViewBackground` instance not `DraggableView` instance.

try this code -

```
-(IbAction)actionYes{
        [draggableBackground swipeRight];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you can not drag a line to connect the Button with the IBAction Method,right?I think it is because you button is define in your popupView,not view controller.Your view controller is not the owner of the buttons, so you can not call the method in controller.Try to define your buttons in Viewcontroller,not in your popupView, it might work